# How to read and edit the word file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How do I read a Word file and be able to edit it in Laravel (phpWord)? I imagine a scenario where the user can open, modify and then save the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for, I think: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Cheers,

Niklas